# Hide striked(and then discounted) Price in woocommerce single product variation product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am failing to get the correct hook to get rid of this kind of prices →

[image]

in woocommerce single product page.

I tried many that were available on the Internet, but could not get rid of any of the `remove_action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code snippet.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', "wt_hide_regular_price", 99, 2);

function wt_hide_regular_price($price, $product)
{
    if(!is_cart() && !is_checkout() && !is_ajax()){
        if ($product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('variation')) {
            return wt_regular_price_for_product($price, $product);
        } 
    }
        return $price;            

}

function wt_regular_price_for_product($price, $product){
    return wc_price($product->get_price());
}
```

Comment: What if I want to hide the whole price? (Striked and discounted, which is equal to regular price and sale price)

Comment: I think in that case This → `return wc_price($product->get_price());` will become → just  `return`

Comment: @wocommerce115 Edited the answer - That's fine for your case I hope. Please accept if it worked for you

Comment: By the way → `return wc_price($product->get_price());` which price will it print or return? regular or sale?

Comment: @wocommerce115 Product active price ( if on sale, sale price else regular )

Comment: Sir, Can you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395602/if-variation-product-then-execute-condition-else-if-simple-then-execute-other-co)

Comment: i just want to remove the strike from the amount how to do this?