# If variation product then execute condition else if simple then execute other condition

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

```
function wooprice(){
    global $product;
    // 1 Get product varations
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // 2 Get one variation id of a product
    $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];

    // 3 Create the product object
    $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );

    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) :
          if( $variation_product ->sale_price !=0 ) :
            echo $variation_product ->sale_price;

          else :
            echo $variation_product ->regular_price;
          endif;

    else :
      echo wc_price($product->get_price());
    endif;

}
```

I am using this function in price.php in my theme.
[image]

This works well if the products are variable products, but fails when the product is simple.

It throws a fatal error if the product is simple:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_available_variations() in /home3/
```

I think this needs to be corrected:

```
else :
 echo wc_price($product->get_price());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function wooprice() {

    global $product;


    if ($product->is_type('variable')) :

        // 1 Get product varations
        $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        // 2 Get one variation id of a product
        $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];

        // 3 Create the product object
        $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_product_id);

        if ($variation_product->sale_price != 0) :
            echo $variation_product->sale_price;

        else :
            echo $variation_product->regular_price;
        endif;

    else :
        echo $product->get_price();
    endif;
}
```

Try this, I have made some modifications to your code

Comment: Mostly Yes, but some minor issues. It is also fetching the currency symbol. I just want the numerical due to some reason + It is showing decimal also, 39.00 for example. I Need integral unless after dot there is some value. [single product](https://www.screencast.com/t/UoVqCEtzVY)  and see → [Variable product seems good](https://www.screencast.com/t/wdPwtHa2qjOr) otherwise it works.

Comment: @wocommerce115 you are right :) - wc_price without currency symbol also possible

Comment: How please clarify? any Filter?

Comment: Sp this give currency → `wc_price($product->get_price()` w/o this we get just numeric.

Comment: sir can u help in this one → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58468876/woocommerce-variation-dropdown-option-tag-add-some-dataset

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your step 1, 2 and 3 inside the `if` block

```
function wooprice(){
    global $product;
    if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) :
          // 1 Get product varations
         $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

         // 2 Get one variation id of a product
         $variation_product_id = $product_variations [0]['variation_id'];

         // 3 Create the product object
         $variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_product_id );


          if( $variation_product ->sale_price !=0 ) :
            echo $variation_product ->sale_price;

          else :
            echo $variation_product ->regular_price;
          endif;

    else :
      echo wc_price($product->get_price());
    endif;

}
```

Comment: In that case even variable product starts to throw fatal error.

Comment: This is some issue: `echo wc_price($product->get_price());`